# New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Tags: azure, variable-assignment, role

I'm trying to change the role from an user. It seems to me that this has to be done by New-AzureRmRoleAssignment as there is no change or set command. When I try to assign a role to a user I get the message:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName "tyler.xxxxx_xxxxx-europe.com"
```

The command I'm using is:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName "tyler.xxxxx_xxxxx-europe.com"  -RoleDefinitionid 4befb2f4-78ae-4354-9bbe-91f67ac41224 -ResourceGroupName "Default-Networking"
```

I copied the id's after doing a get roles.

I don't know why I get the message, can anyone give me advice?

Leon

Answer (score 0):

That combination of arguments does not seem to be supported.

You can do it by using the role definition name instead of the id:

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName 'user@company.com' -ResourceGroupName 'resource-group-name' -RoleDefinitionName 'Reader'
```